# Code deployed successfully but the changes is not showing

Tags: lwc

I am new to LWC. Sometimes when I deployed the code. Code deployed successfully but changes are not showing.
e.g when I add a button or I change the title of the card so that changes do not show on the component. All packages are up to date. Any reason??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the cache issue.

Salesforce does persistent browser caching to improve performance and to load the application faster.

If you want you can disable the caching as follows:

1. Setup.
2. Session Settings.
3. Find Caching settings section on the page.
4. Uncheck Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance.

[image]